# How to set authentication status with redux-toolkit and firebase using onAuthStateChanged?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, redux-toolkit

I am trying to set the auth status for the currently logged-in user using redux-toolkit's createAsyncThunk and firebase's onAuthStatechanged, but I cannot do so. I am trying to implement a private route that can only be accessed if a user is logged in.

***What I have tried**

I create an authService.js file where I created a function checkAuthStatus which calls onAuthStateChanged and returns a user if a user is there else null and then from authSlice, I have exported another function checkUserStatus which returns a promise, and when it gets fulfilled the user will be set to the user returned but the returned value is always null even if the user is logged in.

```
const checkAuthStatus = () => {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    console.log(user);
    return user ? user : null;
  });
};

const authService = {
  registerUser,
  loginUser,
  checkAuthStatus,
};

export default authService;
```

```
export const checkUserStatus = createAsyncThunk('auth/checkAuth', () => {
  return authService.checkAuthStatus();
});
```

```
 .addCase(checkUserStatus.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(checkUserStatus.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.user = action.payload;
        state.isLoading = false;
      });
```

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { checkUserStatus } from './../features/auth/authSlice';
import Loader from './Loader';

const PrivateComponent = () => {
  const { user, isLoading } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(checkUserStatus());
  }, [dispatch]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Loader />;
  }

  return user ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};

export default PrivateComponent;
```

***Problem***
I am not sure why but the function in the authSerice file checkAuthStatus is returning null even if the current user is not null. One more thing is that the user field from the state is not even there in the redux dev tools, check images for more.

Here is my code:-

**authService.js** [authService Page Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e05QP.png)

**authSlice.js** [authSlice function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoTVU.png)  ||  [authSlice extrareducer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB0FR.png)

**PrivateComponent.js** [Private Route component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAt4Y.png)

**App.js** [Routes for app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QrBS.png)

one more thing I have notice is the user state is not even there as redux dev tools are showing

this is pending
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms7oB.png)

this is fulfilled
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clTLN.png)

I have changed the code and now the auth is working but on refreshing the page the user status is user get redirected to login page why?

Answer (score 0):

> How to set authentication status with firebase using onAuthStateChanged ?

There are many way to achieve this:

## Using global store

```js
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setLoginStatus: (state, action) {
      state.loginStatus = action.payload;
    }
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [createUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loginStatus = true;
    },
    [createUser.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loginStatus = false;
    },
  },
});

// trackUserAuth.ts
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      store.dispatch(setLoginStatus(true))
    } else {
      store.dispatch(setLoginStatus(true))
    }
});
```

## Using hooks

```
export const useAuth = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        dispatch(setLoginStatus(true))
      } else {
        dispatch(setLoginStatus(true))
      }
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
}
```

## Using thunks

```js
export const checkAuthStatus = () => (dispatch) {
  const unsubscribe = Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
      dispatch(setLoginStatus(true))
    } else {
      dispatch(setLoginStatus(true))
    }
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}
```

Comment: I have changed the code and now the auth is working but on refreshing the page the user status gets changed and  get redirected to login page why?

Comment: That's another issue

Comment: You need to use redux-persist if you want to persist your state for example

Comment: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist